# You should consider the 1 value in your switch?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm applying for a programming course and we've 59 tasks to do before we being accepted for it. I'm here struggling with a *switch* exercise and I'm hoping someone can help me.

**Show me the code**

*Remember the die roll simulator? Go ahead and transform the if - else if - else statements into a switch statement and check out how it gets easier to read.*

```
var dieRoll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6); 
if (dieRoll === 1) {
    console.log('You roll a 1.');
} else if (dieRoll === 2) {
    console.log('You roll a 2.');
} else if (dieRoll === 3) {
    console.log('You roll a 3.');
} else if (dieRoll === 4) {
    console.log('You roll a 4.');
} else if (dieRoll === 5) {
    console.log('You roll a 5.');
} else if (dieRoll === 6) {
    console.log('You roll a 6.');
} else {
    console.log('This die only has 6 sides man...');
}
```

So now, I'm supposed to turn this into a switch statement and this is where I got to.

```
var dieRoll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
switch (dieRoll)    {
case '1' :
case '2' :
case '3' :
case '4' :
case '5' :
case '6' :
        console.log ('You roll a ' + dieRoll + '.');  
        break;
    default:
        console.log ('This die only has 6 sides man...');
}
console.log(dieRoll);
```

**THE ERROR** - YOU SHOULD CONSIDER THE 1 VALUE IN YOUR SWITCH.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your switch values are strings, not integers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numbers` instead of `strings` in your cases, so instead of:

```
case '1' :
```

use:

```
case 1:
```

And not to mention, `switch` operator uses strict equality(which is `===`) to compare each case against your value. So if you wrote `'0' == 0` that would return `true`, but in switch checks it like: `'0' === 0` and it will return `false`, so be careful with that.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

A `switch`'s `case` must be *exactly* the same value as what's being switched against. With

```
var dieRoll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
```

`dieRoll` will be a number, 1 to 6. It will not be a string, so

```
case <someString>
```

will never be fulfilled.

Use numeric cases instead:

```js
var dieRoll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
switch (dieRoll) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
  case 6:
    console.log('You roll a ' + dieRoll + '.');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('This die only has 6 sides man...');
}
```

But `switch` is quite strange to use here, why not just

```js
console.log('You roll a ' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6) + '.')
```

Comment: I agree that switch is strange to use, but I guess it's just an exercise to convert if/else to switch

Comment: It is just the exercise! But it was the problem using strings! Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The break is omitted the program continues to execute the switch statement until one is found or the end and you forgot to apply it by the end.

I had a same question and i come up it this solution, i know it can be improved but it works

```js
var dieRoll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);


switch (dieRoll){
    case 1:
      console.log('You roll a 1.');
        break;
    case 2:
      console.log ('You roll a 2.');
        break;
    case 3:
      console.log ('You roll a 3.');
        break;
    case 4:
      console.log ('You roll a 4.');
        break;
    case 5:
      console.log ('You roll a 5.');
        break;
    case 6:    
       console.log('You roll a 6.');
        break;
        
  default:
    console.log('This die only has 6 sides man...');
        break;
}
```